# Lazy loading with webpack angular2

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using angular2 full version and i am trying to implement lazy loading. my main routing is as below

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginPage },
    { path: 'reset-password', component: Myaccount },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'app',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    ...ROUTES_APP,
    { path: "sub", loadChildren: "es6-promise?,[name]!./app/sub/sub.module#SubModule" },
];
```

My Sub routing is as below

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { SubAppComponent } from "./sub-app.component";
import { SubHomeComponent } from "./sub-home.component";

export const subRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: SubAppComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "", component: SubHomeComponent }
    ]
  },
];

export const subRouting = RouterModule.forChild(subRoutes);
```

My sub module is as below

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { subRouting } from "./sub.routing";
import { SubAppComponent } from "./sub-app.component";
import { SubHomeComponent } from "./sub-home.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    subRouting,
  ],
  declarations: [
    SubAppComponent,
    SubHomeComponent,
  ],
})
export class SubModule {
}
```

while navigating to sub i am getting error
But i am getting below error

core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: System.import is not a function

Please help me on this/ let me know how to handle lazy loading using webpack

Comment: Your title says webpack, but your error says that you still use `System.js`. Angular2 webpack version doesn't use system.js at all.

Comment: Because of this i got surprised!!

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: no am not using angular-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved above by using require

```
{ path: "sub", loadChildren: () => require("es6-promise!./app/sub/sub.module")("SubModule") }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try **angular-router-loader**

Follow the steps..

```
npm install angular-router-loader --save-dev
```

in your **route** for **lazy loading**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule' }
];
```

for **synchronous loading**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule?sync=true' }
];
```

in **webpack.config.js**

```
test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: [
      'awesome-typescript-loader',
      'angular-router-loader'
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I am getting EXCEPTION: Maximum call stack size exceeded error.
Subscriber.js:227 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Tried by removing all comments again same error. If you have any github link please provide me.